# Remote debugging android application

Tags: android, remote-access, usb-debugging

I have a device that is located in remote area, i have to debug the application that is installed in that device, it is possible to remotely debugging the application, if yes please help me out.

Best Regards,
PLP

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about remote debugging but you can use ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android) .

All you need is to set up a google doc, add the lib to your project and when the app crashes it will send a crash report to that google doc. http://www.acra.ch/. You can also used Splunk MINT library. https://mint.splunk.com/

Answer (score 0):

You debug over wifi network. This plugin will automate the configuration for you:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7856?pr=androidstudio